# Should classes inheriting from MarshalByRefObject remove such inheritance after migrated to .NET 5+?

Tags: c#, .net, marshalbyrefobject

Im migrating a WPF app onto .NET5+, and I see some classes have inherited from MarshalByRefObject class.

Indeed, im not sure how it was used previously, and I myself have no practical experience using this.
I saw InitializeLifetimeService() has been overriden to simply return null, but I dont know what's the purpose of it also.

I had done some study/search and it seems that this class is here for remoting (but I don't see anywhere in the codebase using multiple app domains), which remoting itself no longer exists in .NET5+ (core) world.

While I have marked InitializeLifetimeService() obsolete for now to make my app compile,
question is:

- Wonder if I should/can completely remove the inheritance from MarshalByRefObject?
- or should I keep the class inherited from MarshalByRefObject and just remove any InitializeLifetimeService()/GetLifetimeService() (not sure if MarshalByRefObject still enable some functionality?)

Thanks for help!

Comment: Yes, MBRO is dead and won't be revived.

Comment: No. I'm actively using it (with a rewrite of the old behavior)

Comment: May I know is there any clue (or entry point) that can indicate MBRO is being used inside the application?